# What is this Proxy Object and why am I getting it

Tags: typescript, redux, react-typescript

I am passing a value from my redux store to a function

```
itnerface SelectedProps {
    [key: string]: {
        date: number,
        bar: string[]
    }
}

type FooState = {
    selected: SelectedProps
};

const initialState: FooState = {selected: {}}

    
export const giftSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'whatever',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        thisIsAnAction: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
            const thisGivesMeTheProxyObject = state.foo[action.key].bar 
            console.log(thisGivesMeTheProxyObject)
        }
    }
})
```

> Proxy { : (1) […], : {…} }

What is this `Proxy` object, and why is it not an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for createSlice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) says:

> This object will be passed to createReducer, so the reducers may safely "mutate" the state they are given.

The [documentation for createReducer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer) says:

> To make things easier, createReducer uses immer to let you write reducers as if they were mutating the state directly. In reality, the reducer receives a proxy state that translates all mutations into equivalent copy operations.

So you get a proxy for an array instead of a raw array so you can write simple code that mutates the array while still allowing the reducer to return a whole new object instead of a mutated version of the original object.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using redux-toolkit

When using `createSlice`, it automatically wrap your reducer with [immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) `produce` function.

`produce` allow you to resolve the next state by mutating the state without actually mutating the state in your store. It does so by wrapping the state in a Proxy that will catch all the mutation you are doing in the reducer. (see [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for more info)

If you want to debug your state you can use the function `current` exported by immer (e.g `console.log(current(thisGivesMeTheProxyObject))`)